# How to write common header & footer in Angularjs using ui router states

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am using ui router states. I have two different controllers it may be extend also in future. How to write default and common header & footer.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {});

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // default route
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/first");

    // ui router states
    $stateProvider
        .state('first', {
            url: "/first",
            views: {
                header: {
                    template: '<h1>First header</h1>',
                    controller: function($scope) {}
                },
                content: {
                    template: '<p>First content</>',
                    controller: function($scope) {}
                },
                footer: {
                    template: '<div>First footer</div>',
                    controller: function($scope) {}
                }
            }
        })
        .state('second', {
            url: "/second",
            views: {
                header: {
                    template: '<h1>Second header</h1>',
                    controller: function($scope) {}
                },
                content: {
                    template: '<p>Second content</>',
                    controller: function($scope) {}
                },
                footer: {
                    template: '<div>Second footer</div>',
                    controller: function($scope) {}
                }
            }
        });

});
```

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/karthikreddy/b7cnszdf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/tkf954a5/

You can define your footer and header like :

```
  var header = {
       template: '<h1>Im Header</h1>',
       controller: function($scope) {}

  }
```

and after that use it in your states :

```
 .state('first', {
            url: "/first",
            views: {
                header: header,
                content: {
                    template: '<p>First content</>',
                    controller: function($scope) {}
                },
                footer: footer
            }
        })
```

Comment: Thanks Sylwester. Is there any way to load common header & footer for all controllers.

Comment: @JamesVo if you want to have common header and footer for all controllers change you dom structure to http://jsfiddle.net/tkf954a5/2/

Comment: Okay thanks. How to load sample directive for header.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to put your view (html) and controller code in separate files to make things more readable.

Ui-router allows you to create nested states. With that you can create a base state which has your header and footer, and than add all yout states as nested states.

See: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views for more info.

It would look something like this:

```
.state('base',{
    url: '',
    views: {
        'header': {
             controller: 'HeaderCtrl',
             templateUrl: 'views/header.html'
        },
        'main': {
            template: '<ui-view/>'
        },
        'footer': {
            controller: 'FooterCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'views/footer.html'
        }
    }
})

.state('base.first', {
    url: '/first',
    controller: 'FirstCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'first.html'
})

.state('base.first', {
    url: '/second',
    controller: 'SecondCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'second.html'
})
```

## EDIT

If you don't want to use nested states, you could just put your views and controllers in separate files and include them on each route you make. Instead of having the whole code there, it would be just one string.

Comment: Thanks Jasper, I also tried same way, but it will not working, Can you please write Jsfuddle and send me.

Comment: @JamesVo I'll see what I can do tonight. If you're not planning on using loads of routes and loads of situations where your headers might change, the solution of defining em in separate files, of like sylwester's answer might be the better option for you.